# Addclass to menu issue

Tags: html, jquery

Hello im trying to addclass on my menu but its not working

If you can help me with that much appreciated.

Sorry

HTML

```
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active"><a href="page1.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Page1</a></li>
          <li><a href="page2.php"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Page2</a></li>
      </ul>
```

JS

```
       <script>
var selector = '.nav li';
var url = window.location.href;
var target = url.split('/');
 $(selector).each(function(){
    if($(this).find('a').attr('href')===('/'+target[target.length-1])){
      $(selector).removeClass('active');
      $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('active');
    }
 });
    </script>
```

Comment: @GuyFawkey what's the value of your current url variable?

Comment: @HenryDev http://localhost/admin/

Comment: @GuyFawkey I just posted a solution for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your **if** statement never gets executed. Here's why:

The value of **target** is:

```
var target = url.split('/'); // ["localhost", "admin"]
```

Now if inside your **each** method you're trying to compare two different values:

```
$(this).find('a').attr('href') // page2.php
```

and the value of

```
('/'+target[target.length-1]) // /admin
```

That's why these lines of code never get executed because 'page2.php' is not equal to '/admin'

```
  $(selector).removeClass('active');
  $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('active');
```